# Assigning new row in Pandas for each column value by date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new row for each category for each date in my dataset. I have tried a few different methods with no success.

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question and explain how it failed.

Comment: df= df.melt('Date')